Creating my own Imputer class in Pyspark to be used in a Pipeline doesn´t work
I am using PySpark and I have created my own Imputer class as a subclass of Estimator as follows:
class CustomImputer(Estimator):
    def __init__(self, inputCol, outputCol, strategy, group_column, impute_character=None):
        super(ImputerGrouper, self).__init__()
        ....

    def _fit(self, data):
        ....
  
    def transform(self, new_data):
        ....

Then, I use this CustomImputer in a Pipeline and train it using cross validation, but I get this error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[38], line 13
     10 #tvs = TrainValidationSplit(estimator=pipeline, evaluator=evaluator, estimatorParamMaps=params, trainRatio=0.7)
     11 cv = CrossValidator(estimator=pipeline, evaluator=evaluator, estimatorParamMaps=params, numFolds=3)
---> 13 trained_cv = cv.fit(train)
     14 best_lr = trained_cv.bestModel

File /usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/ml/base.py:205, in Estimator.fit(self, dataset, params)
    203         return self.copy(params)._fit(dataset)
    204     else:
--> 205         return self._fit(dataset)
    206 else:
    207     raise TypeError(
    208         "Params must be either a param map or a list/tuple of param maps, "
    209         "but got %s." % type(params)
    210     )

File /usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/ml/tuning.py:847, in CrossValidator._fit(self, dataset)
    841 train = datasets[i][0].cache()
    843 tasks = map(
    844     inheritable_thread_target,
    845     _parallelFitTasks(est, train, eva, validation, epm, collectSubModelsParam),
    846 )
--> 847 for j, metric, subModel in pool.imap_unordered(lambda f: f(), tasks):
    848     metrics_all[i][j] = metric
    849     if collectSubModelsParam:

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.11/multiprocessing/pool.py:873, in IMapIterator.next(self, timeout)
    871 if success:
    872     return value
--> 873 raise value

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.11/multiprocessing/pool.py:125, in worker(inqueue, outqueue, initializer, initargs, maxtasks, wrap_exception)
    123 job, i, func, args, kwds = task
    124 try:
--> 125     result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
    126 except Exception as e:
    127     if wrap_exception and func is not _helper_reraises_exception:

File /usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/ml/tuning.py:847, in CrossValidator._fit.<locals>.<lambda>(f)
    841 train = datasets[i][0].cache()
    843 tasks = map(
    844     inheritable_thread_target,
    845     _parallelFitTasks(est, train, eva, validation, epm, collectSubModelsParam),
    846 )
--> 847 for j, metric, subModel in pool.imap_unordered(lambda f: f(), tasks):
    848     metrics_all[i][j] = metric
    849     if collectSubModelsParam:

File /usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/util.py:342, in inheritable_thread_target.<locals>.wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
    340 assert SparkContext._active_spark_context is not None
    341 SparkContext._active_spark_context._jsc.sc().setLocalProperties(properties)
--> 342 return f(*args, **kwargs)

File /usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/ml/tuning.py:118, in _parallelFitTasks.<locals>.singleTask()
    113 index, model = next(modelIter)
    114 # TODO: duplicate evaluator to take extra params from input
    115 #  Note: Supporting tuning params in evaluator need update method
    116 #  `MetaAlgorithmReadWrite.getAllNestedStages`, make it return
    117 #  all nested stages and evaluators
--> 118 metric = eva.evaluate(model.transform(validation, epm[index]))
    119 return index, metric, model if collectSubModel else None

File /usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/ml/evaluation.py:111, in Evaluator.evaluate(self, dataset, params)
    109         return self.copy(params)._evaluate(dataset)
    110     else:
--> 111         return self._evaluate(dataset)
    112 else:
    113     raise TypeError("Params must be a param map but got %s." % type(params))

File /usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/ml/evaluation.py:148, in JavaEvaluator._evaluate(self, dataset)
    146 self._transfer_params_to_java()
    147 assert self._java_obj is not None
--> 148 return self._java_obj.evaluate(dataset._jdf)

File /usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py:1322, in JavaMember.__call__(self, *args)
   1316 command = proto.CALL_COMMAND_NAME +\
   1317     self.command_header +\
   1318     args_command +\
   1319     proto.END_COMMAND_PART
   1321 answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1322 return_value = get_return_value(
   1323     answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1325 for temp_arg in temp_args:
   1326     if hasattr(temp_arg, "_detach"):

File /usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/errors/exceptions/captured.py:179, in capture_sql_exception.<locals>.deco(*a, **kw)
    177 def deco(*a: Any, **kw: Any) -> Any:
    178     try:
--> 179         return f(*a, **kw)
    180     except Py4JJavaError as e:
    181         converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

File /usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py:326, in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324 value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325 if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326     raise Py4JJavaError(
    327         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328         format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329 else:
    330     raise Py4JError(
    331         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}. Trace:\n{3}\n".
    332         format(target_id, ".", name, value))

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1856.evaluate.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 486.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 486.0 (TID 1945) (813302be1d05 executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: [FAILED_EXECUTE_UDF] Failed to execute user defined function (`VectorAssembler$$Lambda$4596/0x00000040021625c0`: (struct<familiarity_imputed:double>) => struct<type:tinyint,size:int,indices:array<int>,values:array<double>>).
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.failedExecuteUserDefinedFunctionError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:198)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors.failedExecuteUserDefinedFunctionError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage3.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenEvaluatorFactory$WholeStageCodegenPartitionEvaluator$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenEvaluatorFactory.scala:43)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalSorter.insertAll(ExternalSorter.scala:197)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleWriter.write(SortShuffleWriter.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:161)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:620)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally(SparkErrorUtils.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally$(SparkErrorUtils.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:623)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Encountered null while assembling a row with handleInvalid = "error". Consider
removing nulls from dataset or using handleInvalid = "keep" or "skip".
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler$.$anonfun$assemble$1(VectorAssembler.scala:291)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler$.$anonfun$assemble$1$adapted(VectorAssembler.scala:260)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:36)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach$(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foreach(WrappedArray.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler$.assemble(VectorAssembler.scala:260)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler.$anonfun$transform$6(VectorAssembler.scala:143)
    ... 22 more

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2844)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2780)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2779)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2779)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1242)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1242)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1242)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:3048)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2982)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2971)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:984)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2398)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2419)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2438)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2463)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$collect$1(RDD.scala:1046)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:1045)
    at org.apache.spark.RangePartitioner$.sketch(Partitioner.scala:320)
    at org.apache.spark.RangePartitioner.<init>(Partitioner.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.RangePartitioner.<init>(Partitioner.scala:167)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.OrderedRDDFunctions.$anonfun$sortByKey$1(OrderedRDDFunctions.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.OrderedRDDFunctions.sortByKey(OrderedRDDFunctions.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.BinaryClassificationMetrics.x$3$lzycompute(BinaryClassificationMetrics.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.BinaryClassificationMetrics.x$3(BinaryClassificationMetrics.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.BinaryClassificationMetrics.confusions$lzycompute(BinaryClassificationMetrics.scala:183)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.BinaryClassificationMetrics.confusions(BinaryClassificationMetrics.scala:183)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.BinaryClassificationMetrics.createCurve(BinaryClassificationMetrics.scala:275)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.BinaryClassificationMetrics.roc(BinaryClassificationMetrics.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.BinaryClassificationMetrics.areaUnderROC(BinaryClassificationMetrics.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.evaluation.BinaryClassificationEvaluator.evaluate(BinaryClassificationEvaluator.scala:101)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: [FAILED_EXECUTE_UDF] Failed to execute user defined function (`VectorAssembler$$Lambda$4596/0x00000040021625c0`: (struct<familiarity_imputed:double>) => struct<type:tinyint,size:int,indices:array<int>,values:array<double>>).
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.failedExecuteUserDefinedFunctionError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:198)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors.failedExecuteUserDefinedFunctionError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage3.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenEvaluatorFactory$WholeStageCodegenPartitionEvaluator$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenEvaluatorFactory.scala:43)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalSorter.insertAll(ExternalSorter.scala:197)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleWriter.write(SortShuffleWriter.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:161)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:620)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally(SparkErrorUtils.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally$(SparkErrorUtils.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:623)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Encountered null while assembling a row with handleInvalid = "error". Consider
removing nulls from dataset or using handleInvalid = "keep" or "skip".
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler$.$anonfun$assemble$1(VectorAssembler.scala:291)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler$.$anonfun$assemble$1$adapted(VectorAssembler.scala:260)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:36)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach$(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foreach(WrappedArray.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler$.assemble(VectorAssembler.scala:260)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler.$anonfun$transform$6(VectorAssembler.scala:143)
    ... 22 more

I have figured out this part of the error that says:
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Encountered null while assembling a row with handleInvalid = "error". Consider
removing nulls from dataset or using handleInvalid = "keep" or "skip".

I have checked the results of the pipeline and there is not any record with null values. The thing is that when I leave out the features that I get after applying my custom Imputer it works without any problem.
Anyone has any idea why is it happening? Also, Have I created it properly my CustomImputer?
